# Connect to a remote database on a docker container hosted on an AWS instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker

I have a PostgreSQL database running on a docker container, IP address of the container IP_container, and exposes port 5432, hosted on an AWS Instance of IP address IP_instance.
My security group allows all TCP connexions on port 5432.

I cannot connect on the database from my local computer using IP_instance and port 5432 (cannot find host). Am I missing something ?

Comment: Cannot find host sounds like its an issue with your IP/Hostname. Which IP/hostname are you trying to connect to? Public or Private?

Comment: Does your EC2 instance have a public IP address? Did you start your docker container with `-p 5432:5432` to allow external connections?

Comment: Thanks Ben Whaley this is the right answer, I thought "expose 5432" was enough, please write as an answer so I accept it.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I'd like to connect to a remote machine that's running a psql container too.

Comment: It was that I had to use -p 5432:5432 when i launch my container.